# Drupal 7 post data to external url

Tags: url, drupal-7, http-post, external, http-get

Can anyone offer some direction on how to achieve a programmatic POST request?

I have developed a module which needs to send data to an external URL as part of it's functionality.

To achieve that, I am using the following code:

```
drupal_goto("https://external.secure.co.uk", array(
                'query' => array(
                    'nid'=>$submission->nid, 
                    'sid'=>$submission->sid
                ),
            ));
```

This works successfully and redirects my users to the following url:

```
https://external.secure.co.uk?nid=271&sid=57
```

**The only issue is my data is sent as a GET request. For security reasons I need to find a solution which will allow me to send the data in a POST request.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `[drupal_http_request]`: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7